# Parsley config from 2.0 doesn't work on 2.7

Tags: parsley.js

I just updated from Parsley 2.0.6 to 2.7.2 and my config doesn't work anymore.

This is my config.

```
window.ParsleyConfig = {
        errorClass: 'has-error',
        successClass: 'has-success',
        classHandler: function(Field)
        {
            return Field.$element.parents('.form-group');
        },
        errorsContainer: function(Field)
        {
            return Field.$element.parents('.form-group');
        },
        errorsWrapper: '<span class=\"parsley-help-block\"></span>',
        errorTemplate: '<div></div>',
    };
```

I couldn't find any related documentation in the documents.

Comment: You need to make sure that code is before `parsley.js` is loaded. Otherwise you'll need to pass the object to `$(form).parsley(confighere)`

Answer (score 0):

It probably still works as long as you set `ParsleyConfig` before loading the library.

Parsley used to support different ways (with `ParsleyConfig` and `ParsleyExtend` of being configured, before & after loading, but we're moving away from this. Best is to load the library first (always), then configure it with `$.extend(window.Parsley.options, {...})` as in the doc if need be.

Sorry about the confusion.